# Oracle Coherence - Scheme for Persistence

Tags: caching, oracle-coherence

In Oracle Coherence 12, what is the `backing-map-scheme` that can give a durable storage (NOT database)?

For Ex. Redis writes to a RDB/AOF file and restores KV entries after restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configured Persistence Envrionments in operational config.

```xml
 <persistence-environments>
    <!-- -Dcoherence.distributed.persistence.base.dir=override USR_HOME -->

    <persistence-environment id="stage_env_w_active_store">
            <persistence-mode>active</persistence-mode>
            <active-directory system-property="coherence.distributed.persistence.active.dir">
                    /opt/datastore/staged/active</active-directory>
            <snapshot-directory system-property="coherence.distributed.persistence.snapshot.dir">
                    /opt/datastore/staged/snapshot</snapshot-directory>
            <trash-directory system-property="coherence.distributed.persistence.trash.dir">
                    /opt/datastore/staged/trash</trash-directory>
    </persistence-environment>

    <persistence-environment id="stage_env_w_ondemand_store">
            <persistence-mode>on-demand</persistence-mode>
            <active-directory system-property="coherence.distributed.persistence.active.dir">
                    /opt/datastore/staged/dactive</active-directory>
            <snapshot-directory system-property="coherence.distributed.persistence.snapshot.dir">
                    /opt/datastore/staged/dsnapshot</snapshot-directory>
            <trash-directory system-property="coherence.distributed.persistence.trash.dir">
                    /opt/datastore/staged/dtrash</trash-directory>
    </persistence-environment>

</persistence-environments>
```

Configured the backing-map-scheme persistence in the cache scheme.

```xml
 <distributed-scheme>
      <scheme-name>server</scheme-name>
      <service-name>PartitionedCache</service-name>
      <local-storage system-property="coherence.distributed.localstorage">true</local-storage>
      <backing-map-scheme>
        <local-scheme>
          <high-units>{back-limit-bytes 0B}</high-units>
        </local-scheme>
      </backing-map-scheme>
          <persistence>
         <environment>stage_env_w_active_store</environment>
       </persistence>
      <autostart>true</autostart>
    </distributed-scheme>
```

The **"Active Space Used on disk (MB)"** shows apt space used in JMX JVisualVM.